# Нужна помощь json, обработка пустого ответа

Tags: javascript, php, массивы, json

Подскажите пожалуйста как обработать пустой массив json и если  от сервера получаю ответ такого типа {"result":[],"success":true} вывести сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Таки JS или PHP? В чём проблема проверить длину массива?

Comment: Спасибо решил вопрос сам  if ($obj->result == null)
{
echo "<div class='err_t'>Данные обновляются ...</div>";
}

Comment: @MishaTp, в приведенном Вам примере result не равен null...в приведенном Вами примере result - это пустой массив... и по мне так это совершенно корректный ответ в данном случае а не ошибка